# Attempting to add items from one list to another without duplicates results in empty list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

This is my code so far:

```
duplist = [5,9,14,3,9,97,4,3,23,85,123,5]

singlist = []

for i in (duplist) :
    if i != singlist :
        [str(i)] + singlist
        print(singlist)
```

I am attempting to add all of the items from `duplist` into `singlist` without adding the duplicates.  The result I get from this code is an empty list.  I believe the error is in my if statement line, although I am not sure what operator to use instead of `!=`.

Comment: There's quite some issues here, Will. `i != singlist` compares an integer against a list object. After that, `[str(i)] + singlist` will concatenate `singlist` with `str(i)` but not keep the result (you don't assign it anywhere, right?). For the first case, you're looking for the `in` operator and for the second, the `append` method on lists. In short, I'd suggest you point your browser to https://docs.python.org/3/ and take a look at the tutorial, it'll help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in short by taking the set of the list and constructing a new list from it. Every item in the set is unique.

```
singlist = [i for i in set(duplist)]
```

The long approach:

```
for i in duplist:
    if i not in singlist:
        singlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several issue in your code.

Try this:

```
duplist = [5,9,14,3,9,97,4,3,23,85,123,5]

singlist = []

for i in (duplist):
    if i  not in singlist:
        singlist.append(i)
        print(singlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
singlist = list(set(duplist))
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for an external library:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen

>>> duplist = [5,9,14,3,9,97,4,3,23,85,123,5]
>>> list(unique_everseen(duplist))
[5, 9, 14, 3, 97, 4, 23, 85, 123]
```

This is based on the recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). So you can easily implement it on your own.